# Ordered sampling of uniform variables

Tags: sampling, bioinformatics

I need to sample starting positions in a DNA sequence of given length L.

These starting positions represent starting points of functional domains in DNA sequences. They have a length of d. The starting positions should be distributed uniformly and must have a minimal distance of d between them (functional domains should not overlap). Positions higher then L-d+1 are not possible because functional domains should be complete.

The approach of sampling iterativly a starting position i and procecede with sampling in uniformly in the interval [i+d, L-d+1] does not produce a uniform distribution.

Do you know of any solution to this?

Comment: Depending on the relative sizes of L, d and the number of samples you need, this may work: sample starting positions uniformly without the distance requirement, and reject if the distance requirement is not met.  Typically you're not going to have many functional domain starting points in a sequence, so you should not get too many rejections.

Comment: Surely this is correct but I was wondering for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder. But: I didn't post it as a solution :-)

Comment: Actually, come to think of it: what do you mean by uniform distribution in this case? If e.g. L is 4 and d is 2 while n is also 2, the only solution is to take positions 1 and 3. In what way can this ever be 'distributed uniformly'?

Comment: Surely this would be uniform distributed. Every solution (there is only one) has the same probability (1).

Comment: This question is crossposted on math.SE. Please see the FAQ and meta about crossposts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java'ish pseudo-code:

```
curpos=-d+1
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    maxendrange=L-(n-i+1)*d // make sure there's room for all the remaining domains
    minstartrange=curpos+d //skip the previous domain
    newpos=sampleuniform(minstartrange, maxendrange)
    //store result somewhere
}
```

I haven't proved it or anything, but I'm quite sure this should give equal probability to all possible solutions.

**Edit**: Within the loop, you would have to weight based on how many ways you can position  $n-i$ domains (with the distance restriction) in a sequence of length $L-(curpos+2d)$. It's going to require a lot of calculations that are bound to be more 'expensive' than simply sampling without the distance requirement and rejecting based on it.

As such I return to my original idea (as mentioned in my comment): it will probably be the most effective solution...

Comment: Against your intuition. This is clearly not uniform distributed. :D

Comment: The more I investigate in this problem. The more I think you are right. I have a mathematical approximation. A benchmark will decide which way is the best.