# Distribution of starting points for blocks within DNA

Tags: distributions, spatial

Given a DNA sequence of $L$ I am looking for a distribution to model the starting positions of $k$ blocks with length $w$.

I am starting to investigate in a discrete form of dirichlet distribution but I was curious if any of you ever faced the same problem and how you solved it.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Can the blocks overlap? I seem to recall responding to a question quite like this not too long ago on this same site...

Comment: No they can not overlap. I searched for related topics here but couldnt find any. If you could post the thread?

Comment: Took some looking + I doubt it will be of help to you, [but here it is anyway](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15578/4257)